# Hidden WinForms modal dialogs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog, fullscreen

I have a WinForms app (.NET 4) that has a main form and two modal dialogs as follows:

- FormMain: Run via `Application.Run(new FormMain())`.
- FormSettings: Launched from `FormMain:` `new FormSettings().ShowDialog(this)`.
- FormCredentials: Launched from `FormSettings:` `new FormCredentials().ShowDialog(this)`.

When all three forms have normal borders and sizing, everything works fine. However, this app is supposed to appear in full screen and I use the following code only on `FormMain` to achieve that:

```
        FormMain.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        FormMain.MinimizeBox = false;
        FormMain.MaximizeBox = false;

        FormMain.Text = "";
        FormMain.ControlBox = false;
        FormMain.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        FormMain.TopMost = !Configuration.Debug;
        FormMain.TopLevel = true;
```

The other two dialogs have their `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle`.

So `FormMain` launches `FormSettings` as a modal dialog and `FormSettings` launches `FormCredentials` as a modal dialog. `FormCredentials` ALWAYS disappears behind `FormMain`. In fact any third-level form disappears behind `FormMain`.

Searching for this behaviour brought up suggestions for specifying the form owner which I'm already doing in the call to `ShowDialog(this)`.

Any other reasons for it to behave this way?

**EDIT:** This only happens in release mode so the the line `FormMain.TopMost = !Configuration.Debug` may have something to do with it. That line ensures the end-user cannot get out of the app when it is running as a kiosk.

Comment: Is your ShowDialog(this) calling from thread? And  is TopLevel set for FormCredentials?

Comment: @RavindraSinare: ShowDialog(this) is being called from the UI thread and the TopLevel is only set for FormMain, not for the other two modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this url for TopMost property - you dont need to set anything, comment out this line which does set topmost property, and check, Normally it should work fine.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit : description about TopMost form :

A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost) forms even if it is not the active or foreground form. Topmost forms are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the windows on the desktop. You can use this property to create a form that is always displayed in your application, such as a Find and Replace tool window.